# CRM 2011 - Enabling "BIT"-fields (two options) in a Duplicate Detection Rule

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, duplicate-data, bit-fields

We have a customer who wants to create a "Duplicate Detection Rule" on four fields and one of them is a "Bit"-field (two options).  But when we create the "Duplicate Detection Rule" we can't select any "Bit"-fields.  I guess there is no way to enable the "BIT"-fields?

Otherwise we need to write a service who'll do the job of the "Duplicate Detection Rule".  After a match is found, we need to send an e-mail and the "Duplicate Detection" was also able doing that.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't create a duplication on bit fields you could instead:

1. Create another field (text).
2. Whenever the record is created or the field updated you copy the bit value into the text field with a plugin/workflow.
3. Configure the duplicate detection job on that new text field instead.

Comment: Thx for the answer James, that was also the fix that I told my Customer. I just wanted to know if there was pissibly a supported way of doing this. But clearly there isn't...